# How to confirm and upgrade MongoDB database version in macOS

Tags: mongodb

I use Macports to manage mongodb in macOS. Recently, mongodb not work fine when I use some latest statements.

I execute `mongod --version` in terminal and output "db version v3.4.4". Execute `db.version()` in REPL also expect to be "3.4.4". The binary clearly has been upgraded to the latest version.

Then I try to install mongodb by Homebrew and test the below code. However, the problem is still. Nothing get better.

```
[
  { "$limit": 1 },
  {
    "$project": {
      "hash": {
        "$arrayToObject": [
          [
            { "k": "$_id", "v": "theValue" }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The error raised in mongo shell is:

```
2017-06-13T18:13:44.211+0800 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "$arrayToObject requires an object with keys 'k' and 'v', where the value of 'k' must be of type string. Found type: objectId",
    "code" : 40394,
    "codeName" : "Location40394"
} : aggregate failed :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:16:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:370:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1319:5
```

What's the problem with my mongodb environment?

Comment: If you use `brew` then simply `brew upgrade mongodb` works fine.

Comment: This is MongoDB 3.4 otherwise you would not get the specific error. `where the value of 'k' must be of type string. Found type: objectId"` tells you that you cannot use an `ObjectId` as the value for a "key". This is expected. The question you are asking is *"Is this MongoDB 3.4"*. The reason the statement fails is because you are doing the wrong thing.